# Which files should I be putting in my GitHub Repository

Tags: rust, version-control

I'm making a GitHub repository for my rust project but there are a lot of files, so I was just wondering:

Which files should I be putting in the repository and which ones should I absolutely make sure aren't in the repository?

I've tried searching it up but I just couldn't find anything.

Comment: Cargo should generate a .gitignore file for new projects.

Comment: The general rule (independent of Rust) is that files you edit manually should be under version control, while files that are generated and not meant to be edited manually shouldn't. The only domain-specific exception to this rule is the `Cargo.lock` file, [which should generally be checked in](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/faq.html#why-have-cargolock-in-version-control) in spite of being auto-generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files that definitely need to be included:

- Cargo.toml
- src/

Files that need to be included if you have them:

- build.rs

Files that should be included in most circumstances:

- Cargo.lock
- .gitignore

Files that should be included if you have them:

- README.md, LICENSE.md, etc.
- rustfmt.toml
- .cargo/
- rust-toolchain.toml
- examples/
- tests/
- benches/

Files that should not be included:

- target/

By default, if you create a project with `cargo new` or `cargo init`, Cargo will generate a *.gitignore* file so you don't need to do anything special.

```
# .gitignore
/target
```

Generally, Rust will put any files that need ignoring in *target/*, but of course, if you have non-Rust files that need ignoring, you can add them to *.gitignore*.

Comment: `Cargo.lock` is usually omitted for library only crates, and `rust-toolchain` should be `rust-toolchain.toml` instead for recent `rustup` versions

Comment: @cafce25: The [current starting point guidance is including Cargo.lock in all projects, inclduing libraries](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2023/08/29/committing-lockfiles.html).

Comment: So am I right in saying these four should suffice: main.rs, Cargo.toml, Cargo.lock, .gitignore